# Ninject & MOQ for ASP.NET Integration Testing

Tags: asp.net, ninject, moq, integration-testing

I have a project where I implemented many unit-tests using MOQ which works as expected.

Now I have running some selenium integration tests to check the whole application. The Integration test runs within a unit-test Project in a testclass. When the application comes to the part, where a external webservice is used, it fails because that service is not available. What is the best option to create a Mock for that service?

- Can I change the Ninject-Injections from the ASP.NET at runtime (through the Unit-Test process)? I don't think so. - Details to the setup: The Integration-Test (which is a single unit-test within a test-project), starts the webserver, then starts selenium to connect on the Server and does some Input. I want now to change a IMyInterface with a mockump from the unit-test, without having any if then else in the real ASP.net code.
- Should I make conditional bindings in the ASP.NET Injection setup when the test is running? But that would mean, that all MOQs should already been added at that point, so I can't add/change it from one test to another.
- Or what is the best way for this testing?

Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *through the Unit-Test process*. I thought you are talking about integration tests with selenium. 2nd question: *I can't add/change it from one test to another* means what?

Comment: thanks for your questions. I just added some more details to the question. Let me know if the question is still unclear.

Comment: If your integration test is failing because a required external service is not available, then trying to mock that service is masking a problem that your integration test should be catching, no?

Comment: thanks, but that Interface can't not be tested in our Integration tests, as there is no Access to that component, but we want to test that part of the Software mocking that component.